# Systemd service timing out/restarting every few minutes even though service runs successfully

Tags: systemd

​I have a Raspberry Pi 5 8gb running Raspberry Pi OS and the issue I'm having is that `qbittorrent-nox`, that I installed using apt keeps crashing after around 1 minute and 30 seconds.

Since I have a service that starts `qbittorrent-nox` automatically, it starts back up within 3 secs, but the restarts are annoying and obviously bad for seeding and leeching and I was wondering why this is happening.

Experimenting a bit, in the logs something suggested that the `systemd` service is timing out, and sure enough su-ing to qbit the user for I made to run `qbittorrent-nox` seems to be running fine with no restarting.

The logs and the `systemd` service file has been included before, I used boilerplate code and didn't do much tweaking and do not understand a lot of this either.

```
Service: 
[Unit]
Description=qBittorrent Command Line Client
After=network.target

[Service]
#Do not change to "simple"
Type=forking
User=qbit
Group=qbit
ExecStart=/usr/bin/qbittorrent-nox
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall -w qbittorrent-nox
Restart=on-failure

[Install]                                                                                                                                       
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Service Logs:

````
MAGPi@raspberrypi:~ $ journalctl -xeu qbit.service
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit qbit.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 152795 and the job result is failed.
Dec 18 00:05:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: qbit.service: Consumed 1.685s CPU time.
░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit qbit.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit qbit.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 152795 and the job result is failed.
Dec 18 00:05:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: qbit.service: Consumed 1.685s CPU time.
░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit qbit.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
Dec 18 00:05:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: qbit.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1784.
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit qbit.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Dec 18 00:05:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopped qbit.service - qBittorrent Command Line Client.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit qbit.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit qbit.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 152877 and the job result is done.
Dec 18 00:05:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: qbit.service: Consumed 1.685s CPU time.
░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit qbit.service completed and consumed the indicated resources.
Dec 18 00:05:26 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting qbit.service - qBittorrent Command Line Client...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit qbit.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit qbit.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 152877.
​```
````

Comment: Dec 16 03:01:30 raspberrypi qbittorrent-nox[51369]: QtLockedFile::lock(): file is not opened

Comment: What is that? A new log line? You should just edit your question to add the new info if it is indeed new info.

Comment: Just a note: You really should be using `PIDFile=` if the service truly is forking. It allows Systemd to reliably determine the state of a forking service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Services stay in 'activating' state until systemd receives some kind of ready indication (i.e. the service needs to indicate that it has loaded its configuration, opened its sockets, etc).

The `Type=forking` tells systemd to expect that the program will "daemonize" or "fork to background"; this would be taken as an indication of the service being ready. But because qbittorrent-nox does not do that, the service stays in the 'activating' state forever until it hits a timeout.

Either add the `--daemon` option (preferred), or change `Type=forking` to `Type=simple`.